# How to detect URLs loading in the background in Mozilla Add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a script for Mozilla Firefox Add-on to detect the certain URLs loading in the background and modify the content using pageMod.PageMod. Currently I am using following script:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
    pageMod.PageMod({
      include: ["*.maxcdn.com","*.googleapis.com","192.168.1.1"],
      contentScript: 'window.alert("This website is using CDN/localhost");'
    });
```

The problem with above script is it is only detecting the parent (main URL) and not the scripts/css loading in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebRequest.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/WebRequest.jsm) can instrument all requests.

There also are lower-level primitives ([http observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests) and [content policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIContentPolicy)) on which WebRequest is built. But they are more difficult to implement.